# Can't find headers.authorization

Tags: javascript, node.js

i need to use vanilla node.js, no express and i want to find req.headers.authentification for a JWT implementation but it is empty.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var db = require('mysql');
var bp = require("body-parser");
var qs = require("querystring");
var jwt=require("jsonwebtoken");
require("dotenv").config();
var con = db.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    database: "ESREP"
});
con.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});
http.createServer((req, res) => {

    console.log(req.url + " " + req.method)
    if (req.url == "/") {
        {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
            fs.readFile("Login.html", (err, data) => {
                res.write(data);
                res.end();
            });
        }
    }
    if (req.url == "/" && req.method=='POST') {
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;

        });
        req.on('end', function () {
            post = qs.parse(body);
            console.log(post.EMAIL);
            con.query("SELECT count(*) as NamesCount FROM users where username=" + post.EMAIL + "and password=" + post.PWD + ";", function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (result[0].NamesCount > 0)
                    console.log("Logged!");
            });
        });
    
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
        fs.readFile("Login.html", (err, data) => {
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }
    if (req.url == "/ESREP.css") {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/css' })
        fs.readFile("ESREP.css", (err, data) => {
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }

    if (req.url == "/script.js") {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': '  application/javascript' })
        fs.readFile("script.js", (err, data) => {
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }
    if (req.url === "/Produse.html") {
        {
            con.query("SELECT * from products", function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(result);
                fs.writeFile('db.json', JSON.stringify(result), function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
            });
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
            fs.readFile("Produse.html", (err, data) => {
                res.write(data);
                res.end();
            });
        }
    }

    if (req.url === '/db.json') {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' })
        fs.readFile("db.json", (err, data) => {
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }
    if (req.url === "/Login.html" && req.method == 'GET') {
        {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
            fs.readFile("Login.html", (err, data) => {
                res.write(data);
                res.end();
            });
        }
    }
    if (req.url === "/Login.html" && req.method == 'POST') {
       /**  var body = '';
         req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;

        });
        req.on('end', function () {
            post = qs.parse(body);
           // console.log(post.EMAIL);
            //con.query("SELECT count(*) as NamesCount FROM users where username=" + post.EMAIL + "and password=" + post.PWD + ";", function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                if (result[0].NamesCount > 0)
                   console.log("Logged!");
                   con.query("SELECT owner FROM users where username=" + post.EMAIL+";",function (err, result, fields)
                    {
                    var owner=result[0].owner;
                   });
               
           });
       });
       */
      var user={name : "radw", owner:"silviw"};
      console.log(user,process.env.ACCES_TOKEN_SECRET);
       var token=jwt.sign(user,process.env.ACCES_TOKEN_SECRET);
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'plain/text' })
        res.write(JSON.stringify({token : token}));
        res.end();
    }

    if (req.url === "/Signup.html") {
        {
            var auth= req.headers.authorization; // tried  req.headers.['authorization']; too
            console.log(auth);
            var token=auth && auth.split(' ')[1];
            if(token!=null)
            jwt.verify(token,process.env.ACCES_TOKEN_SECRET, (err) =>
            {
                if(err)
                throw err;
                res.writeHead(403);
                res.end();
                console.log(token); 
            });
      /**       res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
            fs.readFile("Signup.html", (err, data) => {
                res.write(data);
                res.end();
            }); */
        }

    }

    if (req.url === "/Documentation.html") {
        {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
            fs.readFile("Documentation.html", (err, data) => {
                res.write(data);
                res.end();
            });
        }
    }

    if (req.url === "/images/main.PNG") {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'image/jpg' });
        fs.readFile("images/main.png", (err, data) => {
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }

    if (req.url === "/images/signup.PNG") {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'image/jpg' });
        fs.readFile("images/signup.png", (err, data) => {
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }


    if (req.url === "/images/login.PNG") {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'image/jpg' });
        fs.readFile("images/login.png", (err, data) => {
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }
    if (req.url.startsWith("/Produse?add=")) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
        console.log(req.url.substring(13));
        if (req.url.substring(13).length > 0 && /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(req.url.substring(13)) == true) {
            con.query("INSERT INTO `products` (`name`, `qtty`, `date`, `owner`) VALUES ('" + req.url.substring(13) + "', 0 , 27/09/2021 ,'cineva');", function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                con.query("SELECT * from products", function (err, result, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log(result);
                    fs.writeFile('db.json', JSON.stringify(result), function (err) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                    });
                });


            });
        }
        else
            console.log("nu");
        fs.readFile("Produse.html", (err, data) => {
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }
    if (req.url.startsWith("/Produse?addqtt=")) {
        var tok = req.url.substring(16).split("=");
        var qtty = tok[0].split("&")[0];
        var index = tok[1];
        console.log(qtty);
        console.log(index);
        con.query("SELECT qtty from products where name='" + index + "';", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var please_work_javascript = Math.max(0, parseInt(result[0].qtty) + parseInt(qtty));
            console.log(please_work_javascript);
            con.query("UPDATE `products` set `qtty`=" + please_work_javascript + " WHERE name='" + index + "';", function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
            con.query("SELECT * from products", function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(result);
                fs.writeFile('db.json', JSON.stringify(result), function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
            });

        });

        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
        fs.readFile("Produse.html", (err, data) => {
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });

    }
    if (req.url.startsWith("/Produse?rmv=")) {
        var tok = req.url.substring(13).split("=");
        var qtty = tok[0].split("&")[0];
        var index = tok[1];
        console.log(qtty);
        console.log(index);
        con.query("SELECT qtty from products where name='" + index + "';", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            var please_work_javascript = Math.max(0, result[0].qtty - qtty);
            console.log(please_work_javascript);
            con.query("UPDATE `products` set `qtty`=" + please_work_javascript + " WHERE name='" + index + "';", function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });

            con.query("SELECT * from products", function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(result);
                fs.writeFile('db.json', JSON.stringify(result), function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
            });
        });
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
        fs.readFile("Produse.html", (err, data) => {
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }
    if (req.url.startsWith("/Produse?index=")) {
        var index = req.url.substring(15);
        con.query("DELETE from products where name='" + index + "';", function (err, result, fields) {
            if (err) throw err;
            con.query("SELECT * from products", function (err, result, fields) {
                if (err) throw err;
                console.log(result);
                fs.writeFile('db.json', JSON.stringify(result), function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                });
            });

        });
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' })
        fs.readFile("Produse.html", (err, data) => {
            res.write(data);
            res.end();
        });
    }
}).listen(5000, () => console.log("server started !"))
```

more specifically here. Should have had it in the "/Signup.html" part

```
 if (req.url === "/Login.html" && req.method == 'POST') {
      var user={name : "radw", owner:"silviw"};
      console.log(user,process.env.ACCES_TOKEN_SECRET);
       var token=jwt.sign(user,process.env.ACCES_TOKEN_SECRET);
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'plain/text' })
        res.write(JSON.stringify({token : token}));
        res.end();
    }
    if (req.url === "/Signup.html") {
        {
            var auth= req.headers.authorization; // tried  req.headers.['authorization']; too
            console.log(auth); // undefined
            var token=auth && auth.split(' ')[1];
            if(token!=null)
            jwt.verify(token,process.env.ACCES_TOKEN_SECRET, (err) =>
            {
                if(err)
                throw err;
                res.writeHead(403);
                res.end();
                console.log(token); 
            });
         }

    }
```

req.headers.authorization is undefined when i try to print it in the console. Yes, I do want the user to be logged in to sign up. It's creating additional accounts.

Comment: If the client doesn't send any authorization information, the header won't be there.

Comment: Does `req.headers` exist? Is it just the authorization header that's missing? Because if that's the case, then you need to make sure the client sends the header.

Comment: The req.headers does exist. How is the client supposed to send it? I can't seem to find this anywere and i'm new to node.

Answer (score -3):

```
console.log(req.headers)

{
  authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyIjp7Im5hbWUiOiJhYnV5ZSIsImFnZSI6IjIyIn0sImlhdCI6MTY2NTg5NTg0NX0.VPn8vYY39EJ-wPfUBwg97heoxksGrIHNLdwk-gx3tIo',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.29.0',
  accept: '*/*',
  'postman-token': '617626f7-e159-4301-97b9-e942a613b16a',
  host: 'localhost:3000',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '43'
}
```

Just try this `req.headers['authorization']`

Comment: `req.headers['authorization']` is the same as `req.headers.authorization`. Besides, they're actually saying they already tried it and it didn't work either.